# how to save default port and corresponding port in the excel sheet

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I am saving the executed results in excel sheet,The result will be shown as below

```
domainurl   http://example.com/
token.uri   https://example.com/
endpoint    https://example.com/
Points     10.15.13.18,10.13.13.26,10.15.13.4
host    10.15.19.21#10.5.17.2
port    8080#8080
host    10.3.4.16
port    1400
Points  10.35.13.18,10.35.23.16,10.115.13.14
host    abcd0001.unix.sty300.org
port    22
```

I would like to see result like this

```
|A                                               |B
http://example.com/                                80
https://example.com/                               443
https://example.com/                               443
10.15.13.18,10.13.13.26,10.15.13.4                N/A
10.15.19.21,10.5.17.2                            8080
10.3.4.16                                         1400
10.35.13.18,10.35.23.16,10.115.13.14              N/A
abcd0001.unix.sty300.org                          22
```

Note: if it's https or http port should be default 443 or 80, and N/A means there is no port.

Here is the code which i have tired

```
grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri)' $file | grep '^[^#]' | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}' | awk '
BEGIN{
  #print "Filename hostname port"
}
/:[0-9]+/{
  sub(/:/,"\t")
  print;
  next
}
NF==2{
  if($NF~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ || $NF~/[a-zA-Z,]+\..*\.[a-zA-Z,]+$/){
    val=$0
  }
  else{
    if(val){
      print val,$NF
      val=""
    }
  }
}'
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I feel like that first block of text isn't your actual starting input but is instead output that you don't actually want from some other tool. If so, rather than generating that as intermediate output and then having us help you write a tool to convert that to your final output, let us help you write a tool that generates your desired final output directly from your original input. You'd have to provide a sample of that input for us to do that of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a fragile `awk` script that works with this input

```
$ awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80} 
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443} 
       /Points/     {print $2,"NA"} 
       /host/       {h=$2} 
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}' file | column -t

http://example.com/                   80
https://example.com/                  443
https://example.com/                  443
10.15.13.18,10.13.13.26,10.15.13.4    NA
10.15.19.21#10.5.17.2                 8080#8080
10.3.4.16                             1400
10.35.13.18,10.35.23.16,10.115.13.14  NA
abcd0001.unix.sty300.org              22
```

P.S. adding a `next` in each block may prevent some issues...